# Bootstrap dropdown toggle not working on vue spa

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-router

I am using some `bootstrap submenu` on my header and for some unknown reason every time I `router.push` from my login screen to my dashboard which then will load header, the `bootstrap submenu` function or the `dropdown-toggle`not working and to make it work I just simply do manual refresh on the browser.

I don't know why but it just likes the `bootstrap submenu` failed to do something because the header is not loaded when the page created.

So to make it simple I have this configuration on my admin.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <transition 
        enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown "
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOutUp  "
        mode="out-in"
    >
        <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    </transition>

    <transition 
        enter-active-class="animated fadeIn"
        leave-active-class=""
        mode="out-in"
    >
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
</div>
</template>
```

and on my router, I am doing this for login

```
{ path: '/login',
  name: 'login', 
  components: { default: login },
  meta: { notLoggedIn: true }},
```

and then this for the rest of the page for authenticated user

```
{ path: '/',
  name: 'dashboard', 
  components: { default: dashboard,'header': header },
  meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
```

and here is a part of my entire header

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-gear mr-2"></i>
        System
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">

        <router-link :to="{ name:'userCreate' }" class="dropdown-item" active-class="active" exact v-if="currentUser.can && currentUser.can['create_user']">
            <i class="icon-plus22"></i> Add User
        </router-link>

        <!-- divider -->
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> 

        <!-- user -->
        <!-- if board account -->
        <div class="dropdown-submenu" v-show="currentUser.can && currentUser.can['index_user'] && currentUser.id_company == 0">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">
                <i class="icon-users"></i> User
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">

                <router-link :to="{ name: 'userCompany', params:{company:'all'} }" class="dropdown-item" active-class="active" exact >
                    All Company
                </router-link>
                <router-link :to="{ name: 'userCompany', params:{company: currentUser.id_company} }" class="dropdown-item" active-class="active" exact>
                    Board
                </router-link>

                <!-- divider -->
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> 

                <template v-for="company in modelCompany">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'userCompany', params:{company: company.id} }" class="dropdown-item" active-class="active" exact>
                     {{ company.name }}
                    </router-link>
                </template>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- if company account -->
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'userCompany', params:{cu: currentUser.id_company} }" class="dropdown-item" active-class="active" exact v-if="currentUser.can && currentUser.can['index_user'] && currentUser.id_company != 0">
            <i class="icon-users"></i> User
        </router-link>

    </div>
</li>
```

at first, I think because I am doing something wrong with `v-for` part so I remove them and just leave all company and board router-link on there but still having the same issue

and then next I think because of the

```
v-show="currentUser.can && currentUser.can['index_user'] && currentUser.id_company == 0"
```

on div dropdown-submenu class, so for test, I remove that to so just a simple plain dropdown-submenu and it still having the same issue... so now I only have one suspect... it is because adding header component after login is the culprit...

so anyone have an idea how to fix it? maybe there is some bootstrap 4 javascript command to tell the dropdown to reset or re render the whole thing the right way?

or maybe the way I am adding header component is wrong?